# What is the reason of difference in precision between double and long double

Tags: c++, floating-point

## The Problem

I run the code below on two different compilers and each one shows different output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;   

int main()
{
    long double LD1 = 99999.9999;
    long double LD2 = 99999.9999 + 1e-9;
    double D = 99999.9999;

    long long a = LD1 * 10000;
    long long b = LD2 * 10000;
    long long c = D * 10000;

    cout << a << endl << b << endl << c << endl;
}
```

When running on [ideone](http://ideone.com) (chosing C++11) I get the following:

```
999999998
999999999
999999999
```

When running on MSVC13 I get the following:

```
999999999
999999999
999999999
```

## The Questions

1. How can `99999.9999 * 10000 = 99999.9998` (What is the reason behind this problem)?
2. How does the problem get fixed by adding `1e-9`?
3. Why am I getting different values for `a` in the two compilers?

Comment: Please read up about Mrs Mantissa and Mr Exponent and there representation in the divorce court!

Comment: question asked in many forms, many times.